# Load a view with parameters

Tags: views, theming, 8

I got a question regarding the loading of a view within a preprocess function of Drupal 8.

The only working solution I found is this one here:

```
$_block_level_1 = \Drupal::entityManager()->getStorage('block')->load('views_block__myview_ov_block_1');
```

So by using the entity manager.

The view is expecting parameters. How do I send them?

Comment: Have you tried using  views_get_view('xyz_view');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can render view programatically using [views_embed_views()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!views!views.module/function/views_embed_view/8.2.x) and pass views arguments to it. Check example below:

```
\Drupal::service('renderer')->render(views_embed_view('VIEW_NAME', 'DISPLAY_NAME', $ARGS_1, $ARGS_2));
```

Comment: Yes. When doing this kint() goes crazy. It throws errors. I also cannot choose a display. The view is shown by the way.

Comment: Ok Sorry. Got it. Had a cache problem

Answer (score 1):

If you prepare a render element of the view

```
$variables['view_block_1'] = [
  '#type' => 'view',
  '#name' => $name,
  '#display_id' => $display_id,
  '#arguments' => $args,
];
```

you can then render this view in twig:

```
{{ view_block_1 }}
```